# Why is Kotlin `Any` a Class not an Interface?

Tags: kotlin

Kotlin any is a class, with the methods from Java `Object`

```
open class Any() {
    open operator fun equals(other: kotlin.Any?): kotlin.Boolean { /* compiled code */ }
    open fun hashCode(): kotlin.Int { /* compiled code */ }
    open fun toString(): kotlin.String { /* compiled code */ }
}
```

Why is this?

I would have predicted that, as primitives are considered `Any`, but aren't actually `Object`, it would have better to have `Any` an interface that they pretended to implement rather than an class they pretended to inherit.

Comment: Hm, if they would be interface, would you mind handling clashes in multiple interface inheritance?

Comment: I don't think that there's a clash, you only inherit the Set of all interfaces that you or your supertypes implement?

Comment: interfaces can inherit from other interfaces, and you can inherit from multiple interfaces so you get multiple inheritance clashes.

Comment: `Any` implicitly means anything, so all interfaces, if all interfaces have a `hashCode` `equals`, they'll clash, and you'll have to override them and call specific ones `super<Interface1>.equals()` and so on (if needed).

Comment: Again, do you though? If I inherit from 2 classes both of which implement Closeable, I only have one Closeable method

Comment: You cannot inherit from multiple classes o.O

Comment: Primitives are not actually `Any`. But Kotlin hides this fact by automatically boxing a primitive to its object form when it is used as an `Any`. There is no pretending to be anything they are not, it's just the Kotlin compiler using primitive `int` when possible and object `Integer` when needed.

Comment: 42 is Any returns true, it either is Any, or it is pretending to be Any

Comment: Kotlin abstracts away the difference between primitives and their wrapper. At a high level, as far as syntax is concerned, there are no primitives. You only need to think about the distinction when trying to optimize. Even if you do think of them as primitives it wouldn't make any more sense for a primitive to have an interface type than a class type. Also, it wouldn't make sense for an interface to have default implementations of `equals` and `hashcode`.

Answer (score 2):

If Any were an interface, but every single class and interface implicitly inherits from it, then it would have to have default implementations of `equals` and `hashcode`, which wouldn't make conceptual sense for an interface.

Also, since every interface would inherit from Any, there would be a conflict when a class inherits from multiple interfaces. Which super-type implementation of `equals` and `hashcode` would be used? Multiple inheritance of interfaces is a very common situation, so you would be dealing with the complexity of conflicting interface function signatures very frequently rather than once in a blue moon.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand your point here. Interfaces can already override `equals()`, so you can technically inherit `Any`'s methods from different interfaces. How would `Any` being an interface make things different in this respect?

Comment: Also, default implementations of interface methods are actually supported even in Java. Why wouldn't that make sense?

Comment: An interface cannot override functions of Any like `equals()`. And I'm saying it doesn't make *conceptual* sense for an interface to have a default implementation of equals or hashcode. They logically can, but its unclear what the meaning would be because of what an interface represents. An interface is typically only part of a class definition. `equals` and `hashcode` are supposed to represent *all* of a class's state.

Comment: @Tenour04 You're right. For some reason, my IDE failed me. I don't see why there is such artifical limitation, though. Since interfaces can provide implementations for other methods, the problem of multiple inheritance can occur, and it's usually fine. Why is there a special case for `Any`?

Comment: Ah, that last question I do have an answer to http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2013-March/008435.html

Comment: Probably because the class that ultimately inherits from the interface also inherits from Any, so it's creating a conflict. And again, conceptually it doesn't make sense for an interface to act as if it knows the state of the class that will implement it.

Comment: Thanks @DuncanMcGregor that was a nice read! @Tenfour04 inheriting from Any and an interface would be the same inheritance problem as inheriting 2 default method implementations from different interfaces, and there is a mechanism for that: force the user to disambiguate via override. But yes, I agree that in the specific case of `Any`'s methods, these methods really seem tied to the actual state of a class, and it may do more harm than help to allow interfaces to add their behaviour in this respect.

Comment: Yes, there is a mechanism for dealing with it. It’s extra work. I addressed that in may answer when I said you would have to deal with it frequently rather than rarely if it was built into interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

`Object` does not exist in Kotlin.  That is a Java concept.  The fact that after compilation, the byte code is compatible with Java types such as `Object`, is irrelevant from a Kotlin language perspective.

Nat Pryce wrote a really short, very readable article explaining the Kotlin type system.

http://www.natpryce.com/articles/000818.html

In it you'll notice he says:

> Any is the equivalent of Java’s Object class.

But they are not the same thing.  The Java and Kotlin type systems are entirely separate things.

`Any` is not an interface because it serves nearly the same purpose as Java's `Object`.  In Kotlin, `Any?` is the type that includes all types which can be represented in the type system.  And `Any` is the type that includes all types except the `null` value.  So really, `Any?` is Kotlin's `Object`.  It is a type for the same reason that `Object` is a type.

As others have mentioned, Kotlin doesn't have primitives in its type system, so there is no need for them to inherit or pretend to inherit any interface.  They don't exist.

Comment: I agree with the things you say. Can you also say why Any is not an interface?

Comment: Updated my answer to be more explicit about that.